# ¿Como puedo validar CheckBoxes en WPF C#?

Tags: c#, validación, wpf, checkbox, messagebox

**Me pueden ayudar con un ejemplo, porfavor. Lo que quiero es:**

Si hay mas de un CheckBox seleccionado me muestre un MessageBox Diciendo en plural "CheckBox Seleccionados".

y si solo hay un solo CheckBox seleccionado el MessageBox seria "CheckBox Seleccionado".

Pido ayuda con un ejemplo por que no se como hacerlo investigue referente a lo que quiero llegar pero no encontré nada parecido. solo es como validar si hay mas de un CheckBox seleccionado mande un mensaje normal MessageBox y si hay uno solo seleccionado mande otro mensaje MessageBox.

**Algo parecido a esto en WPF C#. pero completo, soy nuevo en esto ténganme consideración.**

```
    private void Btn_Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkboxStatuses = new List<bool>
        {
            CheckBox1.IsChecked,
            CheckBox2.IsChecked,
            CheckBox3.IsChecked,
            CheckBox4.IsChecked,
        }

        if (checkboxStatuses.Where(x => x == true).Count() > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CheckBoxes Seleccionados");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CheckBox Seleccionado");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Proporciona algunos detalles, muestras de investigación y código propio, no llamaras demasiado la atención con una pregunta así poniendo "lo que quiero es"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `CheckBox` en WPF tienen 3 estados, por eso ese código no funciona

- **Verdadero**
- **Falso**
- **Indeterminado**: Esto es cuando la propiedad `IsChecked=null`, es decir que `IsChecked` es del tipo `bool?` (un bool que acepta nulos) y tu lista es solo de `bool`, entonces la solución es tan simple como cambiar el tipo de lista a `bool?`

```
private void Btn_Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkboxStatuses = new List<bool?>() // <-- aquí el cambio
    {
        CheckBox1.IsChecked,
        CheckBox2.IsChecked,
        CheckBox3.IsChecked,
        CheckBox4.IsChecked,
    };
    //el resto  
}
```

Además tu validación está mal, porque si hay cero Checkbox seleccionado te valida como si hubieran muchos.

```
if (checkboxStatuses.Where(x => x == true).Count() == 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Ninguno seleccionado");
}
else if (checkboxStatuses.Where(x => x == true).Count() == 1)
{
   MessageBox.Show("CheckBox Seleccionado");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("CheckBoxes Seleccionados");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo eso quería y si puse ese código como ejemplo pero sabia que tenia errores.